# running gulp changes files by deleting and adding the same content

Tags: gulp

I am currently using Windows and when I use Linux (Fedora) this does not happen but it only happens on Windows. When I run gulp command on git bash. The changes look like this for many files:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-{
-       "globalDependencies": {
-               "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160509150441",
-               "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236"
-       }
-}
+{^M
+       "globalDependencies": {^M
+               "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160509150441",^M
+               "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236"^M
+       }^M
+}^M
```

I tried my best to find the solution for this problem. This is not causing the error but it just that when I try to commit this annoys me because this is not really the change I wanted to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the End of Line character is changing to that of the file system, i.e CRLF (Carriage Return, Line feed) on Windows, or LF (Line Feed) on Linux. When you open a file with CRLF on Linux, the CR shows up as `^M`.

You can create a `.gitattributes` file and set the end of line character with:

```
*.json  eol=lf
*.js    eol=crlf
```

You could also add a gulp plugin that resets the line endings to the format you'd like.

From the Bash terminal run `unix2dos` on the file and see if the `^M` disappears, this will confirm that it's a EOL character issue.

Comment: so this is not the matter of GULP?

Comment: My guess is that Gulp (or a plugin of Gulp) is changing the line ending, and there maybe a way to stop that depending on the specifics of where it's happening, but it's probably easier to tell git the preferred format or add another Gulp plugin to force it to your preferred line ending.